# What is correct way to save image from NSOutputStream to library

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to write UIImage and send data to receive server. I have try but the NSOutputStream only can write maximum 136768 bytes in stream and I only save a fraction of image. Very thankful for help. Here is my code:

From UIImage picker

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,1.0f);
    NSLog(@"%d",imgData.length);
    NSMutableData *completeData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    [completeData appendData:imgData];

    NSInteger bytesWritten = 0;
    while ( completeData.length > bytesWritten )
    {


        //sending NSData over to server
        NSInteger writeResult = [outputStream write:[completeData bytes]+bytesWritten maxLength:[completeData length]-bytesWritten];
        if ( writeResult == -1 )
            NSLog(@"error code here");

        else
            bytesWritten += writeResult;

        if (bytesWritten == writeResult) {
                        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        }
    }

}
```

Stream delegate

```
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)aStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode
// An NSStream delegate callback that's called when events happen on our 
// network stream.
{
#pragma unused(aStream)
    assert(aStream == self.networkStream);

    switch (eventCode) {
        case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted: {
            [self _updateStatus:@"Opened connection"];
        } break;
        case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable: {


            if (aStream == self.networkStream) {

                uint8_t buffer[5000];
                int len;

                while ([self.networkStream hasBytesAvailable]) {

                    len = [self.networkStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
                    NSLog(@"len=%d", len);

                    if (len > 0) {

                        NSData *pictureData = [NSData dataWithBytes:buffer length:len];

                        [sharedManager.pictureMutableData appendData:pictureData];

                        NSLog(@"%d",sharedManager.pictureMutableData.length);



                    }

                }
            }
        case NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable: {

            [self _didReceiveDataImage:sharedManager.pictureMutableData];

            NSLog(@"%d",sharedManager.pictureMutableData.length);
                   } break;
        case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred: {
            [self _stopReceiveWithStatus:@"Stream open error"];
        } break;
        case NSStreamEventEndEncountered: {
            // ignore
        } break;
        default: {
            assert(NO);
        } break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is strange:

1. You implement the events for an *input* stream (`NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable`).
2. The data is not written in one part, but you have to send it part by part. The size of the part is determined by the OS. If the data is larger, you have to write the next part in the delegate method for the event `NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable`. But you do not write there. Instead you *set* *received* data!?

Have a look here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/WritingOutputStreams.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002274-1002233